# Force tokenmismatchexception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on a Laravel application that someone else made, the site has some problems with the `tokenmismatchexception`I developed some code to deal with it. The session are being saved in the database, so actually what I want to know is what can I do to emulate a defeted token? I tried deleting and editing the register from the session table but it gets renewed, and I just want to force an error to see how the application respond to this situation. Thanks

Comment: Just delete your cookies?

Comment: @derdida yeah! it works, thanks!!

Comment: Fine :) Ill add it as answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i said on Comments:

Just delete your cookies while leaving the page with the form open, then submit it without refreshing first.

Comment: Clarification: delete your cookies while leaving the page with the form open, then submit it without refreshing first. Refreshing will just set another token. :-D